# How to debug this Testcafe case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, ecmascript-6, testcafe

I've written 12 tests in total so far for this project and there is one error that is occurring in different places depending on the tests composition.

My question is about how to debug this issue. 
I'll share the error and the test sample in hope that someone else had a similar problem and has an idea on how to approach it.

The `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` is the error in question, and there is no reference to the where it occurred.

From the tests perspective, the next action was supposed to be clicking a button and getting a popup for creating a new product.

The application works correctly and without problems, it's just the e2e tests that report the problem.

The reported test in question works in isolation.
Excluding this test, the error manifests on another test.

At the end of this post, you'll be able to see the error thrown when this test is skipped.

[image]

```js
fixture('Select a product from the list:')
  .page('http://localhost:3000/products');

// @TODO Fix e2e test
test
  .before(generateProducts(page, 1))
  ('clicking the "Close detail" button should return us to the products page.', async t => {
    const productsListItem = await page.listContainer.child(0);
    await t
      .click(productsListItem)
      .click(page.closeDetail)
      .expect(page.productsPageTitle.innerText).eql('PRODUCTS')
  })
  .after(removeGeneratedProducts(detailedProductPage, 1));

test
  .before(generateProducts(page, 2))
  ('selecting another product, while the previous is still opened, should refresh the preview with the new selection.', async(t) => {
    const productListItems = await page.listContainer.find('li');

    const productsListItem0 = await productListItems.nth(0);
    const productsListItem0Title = await productsListItem0.find('[data-test-id="name"]').innerText;

    const productsListItem1 = await productListItems.nth(1);
    const productsListItem1Title = await productsListItem1.find('[data-test-id="name"]').innerText;

    await t
      .click(productsListItem0)
      .expect(page.productTitle.textContent).eql(productsListItem0Title || 'Missing product\'s name')
      .click(productsListItem1)
      .expect(page.productTitle.textContent).eql(productsListItem1Title || 'Missing product\'s name')
  })
  .after(removeGeneratedProducts(detailedProductPage, 2));


fixture('Field state updating when switching between products with an open Quick Edit view')
  .page('http://localhost:3000/products');

test
  .before(async t => {
    await t
      .click(page.showAddProductFormButton)
      .typeText(page.nameField, `${chance.name()} ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1}`)
      .click(page.createNewProductButton)

      .click(page.showAddProductFormButton)
      .click(page.createNewProductButton);
  })
  ('Products quick edit navigation should update the view, and not inherit the values of the previous product', async(t) => {
    const productListItems = await page.listContainer.find('li');
    const productsListItem0 = await productListItems.nth(0);
    const productsListItem1 = await productListItems.nth(1);

    await t
      .click(productsListItem0)
      .expect(page.productTitle.textContent).eql('Missing product\'s name')
      .click(productsListItem1)
      .click(productsListItem0)
      .click(productsListItem1)
      .click(productsListItem0)
      .expect(page.productTitle.textContent).eql('Missing product\'s name')
      .click(productsListItem0)
  })
  .after(removeGeneratedProducts(detailedProductPage, 2));
```

```html
Don't expect results when running the code. I've used this feature to nicely import the code, nothing more.
```

The same error on a different test when the original test is skipped.
[image]

Comment: Hi. 
This error means that a js error appeared on your page. Sometimes it relates to some issue on a page. Sometimes it's a TestCafe issue (when TestCafe proxies the page in an incorrect way).
The best way to debug it is the following:
1) When tests are started, open developer tools in the browser;
2) Check that the 'Pause on exceptions' option is enabled;
3) When the error occurs, you can see its callstack in the browser's console. With this, you can see whether it's an issue on your page or in TestCafe code.
You can skip js-errors on the page with the `-e, --skip-js-errors` option.

Comment: Also you can try the latest TestCafe `dev` version (call `npm install testcafe@dev`). With it you can run the test with the `--debug-on-fail` option. Test run will be paused and switched to the `debug mode` once the test fails.

Comment: Hi Alexander, 
thanks a bunch for these suggestions. 
I'll check them out as soon as I'm able to replicate the problem. Today everything runs smoothly no matter what. By the way, I really love Testcafe, it's so easy to use, and the default reporter is great. I just have to get a hang on debugging these end cases. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [current product version](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/blog/testcafe-v0-23-0-released.html) (0.23.0), we've introduced the [Stop Test Run After the First Test Fail](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--sf---stop-on-first-fail) option. You can now configure TestCafe to stop the entire test run after the first test failure. This saves your time when you fix problems with your tests one by one.

Using the mentioned [--debug-on-fail](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--debug-on-fail) option, you can specify whether to automatically enter the debug mode when a test fails. If this option is enabled, TestCafe pauses the test when it fails. This allows you to view the tested page and determine the cause of the failure.

In addition, you can use the [--debug-mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-d---debug-mode) option. In this mode, test execution is paused before the first action or assertion allowing you to invoke the developer tools and debug.

See also: [TestCafe Debugging](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/debugging.html)